# How to escape Backslashes from wcf Web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, wcf

Hi my wcf webservice is like follows

```
  public string GetValues(int CompanyCode)
        {
            Logger.EnterFunction();
            string value = "[";
            try
            {
                Logger.EnterFunction();
                int Comppany = CheckCompanyValid(CompanyCode);
                if (Comppany == 1)
                {

                    value += "{";

                    value +=  "IncomeAmount:" + GetIncomeAmount(CompanyCode).ToString();
                    value += ",\"ExpenseAmount\":" + GetExpenseAmount(CompanyCode).ToString().Trim();
                    value += ",\"NetProfitLossAmount\":" + GetNetProfitLoss(CompanyCode);
                    value += ",\"CustomerOutStanding\":" + GetCustomerOutStanding(CompanyCode);
                    value += ",\"SupplierOutStanding\":" + GetSupplierOutStanding(CompanyCode);
                    value += ",\"CorporationTaxAmount\":" + GetCorporationTaxAmount(CompanyCode);
                    value += ",\"VATAmount\":" + GetVATAmount(CompanyCode);
                    value += ",\"PayeAmount\":" + GetPayeAmount(CompanyCode);
                    value += ",\"NumberOfBankTransactionUnProcessed\":" + GetNumberOfBankTransactionUnProcessed(CompanyCode);
                    value += ",\"NumberOfQueries\":" + GetNumberOfQueries(CompanyCode);
                    value += ",\"ReserveValue\":" + GetReserveValue(CompanyCode);   
                    value += ",\"AllBankBalance\":" + GetAllBankBalance(CompanyCode) + "}";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error(ex);
            }
            value += "]";
            Logger.LeaveFunction();

            return value;

        }
```

Which is fine and runs for the following output

```
"[{IncomeAmount:117730.8400,\"ExpenseAmount\":43391.5400,\"NetProfitLossAmount\":74339.3000,\"CustomerOutStanding\":107541.0400,\"SupplierOutStanding\":6173.6700,\"CorporationTaxAmount\":1000.0000,\"VATAmount\":700.0000,\"PayeAmount\":3250.0000,\"NumberOfBankTransactionUnProcessed\":22,\"NumberOfQueries\":2,\"ReserveValue\":(73339.30),\"AllBankBalance\":5299.5800}]"
```

There is no issues but my problem is i don't want the slashes which is killing me from one day
i have tried many things like **escaping** , **Replacing** and using **memorystream** but some how its remains same

I know about newtonsoft.dll but I can not use it 
I hope i explain you clearly....thanks in advance.......

One more thing to add 
I also tried using classes but result is still same...........

Comment: Isn't this just something that can be done by the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx)

Comment: I don't know about this can you help me little bit so can do it my self.....@rene

Comment: @rene could be more specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you reading the output string from?

The code you've supplied looks correct to me, assuming you want `",\"NetProfitLossAmount\":"` to be rendered as `","NetProfitLossAmount":"` - this is what the \ character is for; it escapes the " so that it's treated as part of the string, and not a terminator. Visual Studio debugging tools tend to express strings in escaped form so that you can readily paste them back into C# and have it work like you expect. To check that the service is really returning the text you expected, write the result to a file and see what **that** looks like.

Comment: Ya i know this by googling already but is there any ways i can terminate it?

Comment: ...What? Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by that comment. I've just taken the relevant parts of the code you posted and checked that it does what you're expecting - when you write the result **to the console** the slashes don't appear.

Comment: Ya i know but in browser its render same as i write output here

Comment: When i watch my output to visual studio its remains same as i expected

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you think the problem is. Could you please explain the problem more clearly, or [continue the discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is/was that you used a string as return type where you really wanted to return a json object. Due to the fact that the string contained your json the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) escaped the double-quotes in it to prevent confusion for the clients.

If you create a proper DataTransferObject you can fully utitlize the DataContractJsonSerializer without all the custom buildup of serialization strings you have in your current solution.

The following changes are needed:

- Add Company class with properties
- Change the interface with a the new return type of GetValues
- Adapt the implementation of GetValues to return an array of Company Classes

#### The Company Class

```
[DataContract]
public class Company
{
    [DataMember]
    public int IncomeAmount { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int ExpenseAmount { get; set; }
    /// add the other properties your self
}
```

#### Service Interface

Notice you have to return an array of Company classes!

```
[WebGet(
    UriTemplate = "/GetValues?CompanyCode={CompanyCode}", 
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,  
    RequestFormat =  WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
Company[] GetValues(int CompanyCode);
```

#### Service Implementation

```
public Company[] GetValues(int CompanyCode)
{
    Logger.EnterFunction();
    var companies = new Company[1];
    try
    {
        Logger.EnterFunction();
        int Comppany = CheckCompanyValid(CompanyCode);
        if (Comppany == 1)
        {
            companies[0] = new Company
                {
                    IncomeAmount = GetIncomeAmount(CompanyCode),
                    ExpenseAmount = GetExpenseAmount(CompanyCode),
                    // etc add your other properties here
                };
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error(ex);
    }
    Logger.LeaveFunction();
    return companies;
}
```

#### To verify

The WCF/http pipeline will send you back an json string if the Content-Type header of the request is of the type json as well. Use a low level httprequestbuilder like Fiddler to emulate that.

**Request**

> GET /Service1.svc/GetValues?CompanyCode=3 HTTP/1.1
>   User-Agent: Fiddler
>   Content-Type: application/json
>   Host: localhost:42369

**Response**

> [{"ExpenseAmount":3,"IncomeAmount":42}]

Comment: Thanks rene i have done it anyways i don't saw any problem with this code also....

Answer (score 0):

It should be looks like

```
  [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetValues?CompanyCode={CompanyCode}")]
        Stream GetValues(int CompanyCode);
```

and from the method

```
 value += "]";
            Logger.LeaveFunction();
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/json";
            string json =(value);   
            return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
```

If you don't use stream your output will be bare without cloths so it should be surrounded by the memory stream which will gives you pure output as i required in question......thanks